# gem install gollum gives me error bits/c++config.h not found in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, rubygems, clang, gollum-wiki

When I run

```
sudo gem install gollum
```

or

```
sudo gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/local/lib/icu --with-opt-include=/opt/local/include/ --with-opt-lib=/opt/local/lib/
```

I get the following error:

```
compiling transliterator.cpp
In file included from transliterator.cpp:4:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/string:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Maybe there's some flag I need to set so that the compiler can find these libraries? 
Mac OS Sierra version 10.12 , 
here  the gcc version (Xcode installed) :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post needs a little bit of cleaning up and I'll try and help with that so that you get high-quality responses to your question. Mainly you want to make your code blocks use block syntax and organize your question a touch better. I'll post an edit.

Comment: Thanks very much !